# Instance is being removed from the group

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have instance group with auto-scaling 1->2 and 2->1 But for some reason, the 2nd copy has been removed for several days.

Tried to remove that instance from the group and got this error:

```
Operation type [compute.instanceGroupManagers.deleteInstances] failed with message "Cannot delete instance https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/silver-pact-<value>/zones/us-central1-a/instances/instance-group-glca that was already abandoned."
```

Is it possible to delete an unnecessary instance and return the number of instances in the group to 1 while there is no high load?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question lacks details on how everything is configured and what command generated the error. Edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

If the instance is already abandoned, that instance is not part of the instance-group anymore.

You cannot use `gcloud compute instance-groups managed delete-instances` command to delete the instance because it is not part of an instance group.

You should be able to delete the whole vm with the regular command to deletes vm:

**Warning: this will delete your VM!!!**

```
gcloud compute instances delete instance-1 --zone=us-central2-a
```

Comment: I just need to remove one instance in managed instance group. Any ideas on how to do this?